# What is Chrome default cache size limit?

Tags: google-chrome, browser-cache

What is Chrome default cache size limit? Where it can be found?

Answer (score 8):

According to [Chromium source](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/net/disk_cache/cache_util.cc), it uses kDefaultCacheSize = 80 * 1024 * 1024 Bytes --> 80MiB and applies the first matching rule of the following to determine the actual (disk, HTTP) cache size

- 80% of the available space if there is not enough space to use kDefaultCacheSize
- kDefaultCacheSize if it uses 10% to 80% of the available space
- 10% of the available space if the target size (2.5 * kDefaultCacheSize) is more than 10%
- the target size (2.5 * kDefaultCacheSize) if it uses 10% to 1% of the available space
- 1% of the available space

So that should be **10% of the available disk space** at startup in the common case, with a moderately filled HDD.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, the common cache size should be **1% of the available disk space**, not **10%**, considering most users should have more than 20,000MiB of available space. Or maybe a fixed cache size of 200MiB for users with less than 20,000MiB but more than 2,000MiB. That 10% only applies if user has less than 2,000MiB available (but more than 800MiB). I doubt most users fill storage to the brim like that, at least on desktops, though this might be more common in phones if the same calculation applies there.

Comment: I think in practice there's an upper bound from https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/net/disk_cache/cache_util.cc#223 of 4 * kDefaultCacheSize (= 320 MiB). So in the case that the free disk space exceeds 400 * kDefaultCacheSize (= 32000 GiB ~ 32 GB), that hard limit applies. When I check cache usage empirically on devices that have way over that much free space (e.g., ~100 GiB free), I see cache usage in the 240-320 MiB range.

Answer (score 3):

There **isn't** a default size for Cache in Google Chrome.
The maximum size of the cache is calculated as a percentage of available disk space. The default size is calculated at start time.

From: http://gent.ilcore.com/2011/02/chromes-10-caches.html

> The maximum size of the cache is calculated as a percentage of
>   available disk space. The contents can be viewed at
>   chrome://net-internals/#httpCache. It can be cleared manually at
>   chrome://settings/advanced or programmatically by calling
>   chrome.benchmarking.clearCache() when Chrome is run with the
>   --enable-benchmarking flag set. Note that for incognito windows this cache actually resides in memory.

Also, the article explains other 10 type of Caches like Memory Cache, DNS Cache etc.

Comment: chrome://net-internals/#httpCache doesn't show me anything.... it says capturing, but nothing ever shows up

Comment: @Michael - Which version of chrome are you using?

Comment: 67.0.3396.99 (64-bit, Linux)

Answer (score 3):

1. Create desktop shortcut
2. Target: `"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disk-cache-size = 1073741824` (In bytes, here 1GB are allowed)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).